# Which player is affected by Tolarian Winds?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Tolarian Winds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTolarian%20Winds%5d) says

> Discard all the cards in your hand, then draw that many cards.

Seems simple, but my opponent and I disagree. I take the text literally, draw is directed at the controller - he tries to play it if worded "Have target opponent (or any player)...

I tried looking at gatherer for this, but no relevant rulings. He claims 'house rules'. I say boo-ya, I want MTG rules only.

Comment: Your opponent lacks a fundamental understanding of the rules...

Comment: They also lack an understanding of the term "house rules", which generally means "an adjustment of the rules this playgroup seems appropriate and is know to all players or explained to those unaware prior to playing" - not "my house, my rules".

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, the effect will apply to the Tolarian Winds' controller. I believe the relevant rule is 608.2c:

> 608.2c The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions in the order written. (...)

As the controller is the one following the instructions they are the one designated by "your" in the card text.

Comment: Also: "109.5. The words “you” and “your” on an object refer to the object’s controller, its would-be controller (if a player is attempting to play, cast, or activate it), or its owner (if it has no controller). ..."